# Is there an equivalent for getIndex() for CK Editor Version 4.4.6?

Tags: ckeditor

I know the method getIndex() was introduced in version 4.5 but we are currently unable to update our CKEditor version as it is tied to an enterprise software package. Is there a way to mimic the getIndex() function in CKEditor versions prior to version 4.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to [CKEDITOR.tools.getIndex()](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.tools-method-getIndex), you can just use JavaScript's own [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) (not for Internet Explorer though):

```
function isBigEnough(element) {
  return element >= 15;
}

[12, 5, 8, 130, 44].findIndex(isBigEnough); 
// index of 4th element in the Array is returned,
// so this will result in '3'
```